# Trimming the grep output

Tags: grep

I am using grep to extract the expiration date from a WHOIS record. The command line I use is:

```
whois -H domainname.com | grep -m 1 'Expir'
```

and I get what I need, i.e. the line with the first match containing 'Expir'.
However, I would like to trim this output and get only the date, i.e. xxxx-xx-xx.

Currently, the output looks like this:

```
   Registry Expiry Date: 2018-01-23T16:07:52Z
```

There are extra characters after the date, delimited by the character T, as well as extra characters before the date.
How can I eliminate all those and keep the date only?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$ whois -H google.com | grep -oP 'Expiry Date: \K.*(?=T)'
2020-09-14
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I don't understand any of it, but it works :)